# Next.js lint to list fixed files

Tags: next.js, eslint

I have added --fix option in package.json to automatically fix problems,

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "lint": "next lint --fix"
}
```

this is how my .eslintrc.json looks like,

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": ["error", "single"]
  }
}
```

this is working as expected, the double quotes are fixed to single quotes by ESLint. However, how can I configure it to display the modified files on the console?

Comment: I would recommend configuring single quotes through prettier rather than eslint. `.prettierrc.json`

`{ "singleQuote": true }`